# Check the content in script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added span tag for all comma using jquery  to  adding class for css. unfortunately It adds span tag inside script and get collapsed.I want to check the content is not in script tag and add span tag.I want to replace all comma (,) except the content in script tag.

```
if ($("#overview").length > 0) {
   $("#overview").html( $("#overview").html().replace(/,/g,"<span class='comma'>,</span>")); 
}
```

Comment: The location of a script tag *should* be irrelevant in the vast majority of cases - consider moving them away. Also, changing the content of script content *after* the script is on the page should not have any effect, since the script will have already run.

Comment: Does the script content have to be inside overview element? Just  move it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful because the **html** attributes can also contain text with '**,**'.

One way to solve this problem is iterate by the TextNodes, and for each one split the value in multiples **TextNodes** separated by a **SpanNode**.

```js
// get all text nodes excluding the script
function getTextNodes(el) {
  if (el.nodeType == 3) {  // nodeType 3 is a TextNode
    return el.parentElement && el.parentElement.nodeName == "SCRIPT" ? [] : [el];
  }
  return Array.from(el.childNodes)
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(getTextNodes(item)), []);
}

// this will replace the TextNode with the necessary Span and Texts nodes
function replaceComma(textNode) {
  const parent = textNode.parentElement;
  const subTexts = textNode.textContent.split(',');  // get all the subtexts separated by ,

  // for each item in subtext it will insert a new TextNode with a SpanNode
  // (iterate from end to beginning to use the insertBefore function)
  textNode.textContent = subTexts[subTexts.length - 1];
  let currentNode = textNode;
  for(var i = subTexts.length - 2;  i>= 0 ; i --) {
    const spanEl = createCommaEl();
    parent.insertBefore(spanEl, currentNode);
    currentNode = document.createTextNode(subTexts[i]);
    parent.insertBefore(currentNode, spanEl)
  }
}

// create the html node: <span class="comma">,</span>
// you can do this more easy with JQUERY
function createCommaEl() {
  const spanEl = document.createElement('span');
  spanEl.setAttribute('class', 'comma');
  spanEl.textContent = ',';
  return spanEl;
}

// then, if you want to replace all comma text from the element with id 'myId'
// you can do
getTextNodes(document.getElementById('myId'))
  .forEach(replaceComma);
```